# AndroidStudio Problem with Relative Layout

Tags: android

I have a problem with `RelativeLayout`. In design view I can see my Layout works perfect, but in runtime one `EditText` goes down from the screen.

Here is some code of my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvInicio"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:text="@string/dialog_titulo"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvPrimero"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
    android:text="@string/dialog_max"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etMaximo"
    android:layout_width="111dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tvPrimero"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/dialog_etMax"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etMinimo"
    android:layout_width="111dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="151dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/dialog_etMin"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvSegundo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etMinimo"
    android:text="@string/dialog_maxmin"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etMaximo2"
    android:layout_width="111dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvSegundo"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/dialog_etMax"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTexto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/etTexto"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:text="@string/diaog_textoTitulo"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etTexto"
    android:layout_width="193dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="180dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/diaog_etTextoTitulo"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="360dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCancelar"
        android:layout_width="176dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="19dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/etTexto"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/etTexto"
        android:background="@drawable/boton_redondeado2"
        android:text="@string/iniciar_sesion_cancelar"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnGuardar"
        android:layout_width="178dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnCancelar"
        android:layout_marginEnd="9dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
        android:background="@drawable/boton_redondeado"
        android:text="@string/diaog_guardar"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azrt9.png)

Run time view look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gcu9G.png)

Can someone help me because I'm desperate. My English is bad, so I accept edits

Comment: use constraint layout https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/ for it. Relative layout is not responsive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `RelativeLayout`, instead of using

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_marginBottom="180dp"
```

like you are doing in the EditText with with id `@+id/etTexto`, you can simply write this code: `android:layout_below="@id/etMaximo2"`
You can even place some `android:layout_marginTop` if you want to add more space between the two Views.

P.S. For testing in the design view, know that you can change the dimensions of the device you're testing, so you can see in the "Preview" window what it would look like on device with different screen sizes. You can change this in the top toolbar of the preview window.

I hope this helps you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete `android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"` and then clean your project after the clean, run again. 
Make sure that your Relative Layout is closed right after the linear ends
 `</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>`

Does it work now?

I used this xml and it worked on a Nexus 5 emulator

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvInicio"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:text="TEST"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvPrimero"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
    android:text="test"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etMaximo"
    android:layout_width="111dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tvPrimero"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="test"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etMinimo"
    android:layout_width="111dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="151dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="test"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvSegundo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etMinimo"
    android:text="test"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etMaximo2"
    android:layout_width="111dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvSegundo"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="test"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTexto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/etTexto"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:text="test"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etTexto"
    android:layout_width="193dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

    android:layout_marginBottom="180dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="this should stay right here"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="360dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCancelar"
        android:layout_width="176dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="19dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/etTexto"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/etTexto"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="button"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnGuardar"
        android:layout_width="178dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnCancelar"
        android:layout_marginEnd="9dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="button"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: updated my answer , did a test run and it works for me as in your picture.

Answer (score 0):

Give this `id` to the `LinearLayout`:

```
android:id="@+id/layout"
```

and add this attribute to `etTexto`:

```
android:layout_above="@+id/layout"
```

also adjust the bottom margin as you like.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try putting it below EditText that is above it?

**Remove**

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_marginBottom="180dp"
```

**Add**

```
android:layout_below="@+id/etMaximo2"
```

**Result**

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etTexto"
    android:layout_width="193dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etMaximo2"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/diaog_etTextoTitulo"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
```

Then set some top margin `android:layout_marginTop="{some value}dp"` to make it look like you want.